# Can't assign associate object in one-to-one association Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a merchant and a user model define as a one-to-one association.

Merchant model

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, dependent: :destroy
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :username, uniqueness:{case_sensitive: false}
    belongs_to :gender
    belongs_to :merchant, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
```

Gender model

```
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many: users
```

I have no problem creating a User obj and saving it to the DB. There also no problem assigning the Gender obj `g` to the User obj `u`.

```
g = Gender.create(gender: "M")
u = User.create(username: "tester", first_name: "Tester", last_name: "Mac", email:"emadail@y.com", passwd:"passwddfaff ", salt: "fdafeagda", active: true, gender:g)
```

Problem: can't assign existing User `u` to the Merchant obj `m`

```
m = Merchant.create(user: u, company: "company")
```

it returns

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `merchant_id'. 
Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer`    etc. (called from irb_binding at (irb):17)

D, [2013-11-12T15:11:45.838908 #834] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  COMMIT
D, [2013-11-12T15:11:45.839365 #834] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2013-11-12T15:11:45.842261 #834] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `merchants`     (`company`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('company', '2013-11-12 23:11:45', '2013-11-12    23:11:45')
E, [2013-11-12T16:58:22.311452 #1032] ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `merchants` (`company`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('mystorebag', '2013-11-13 00:58:22', '2013-11-13 00:58:22')
```

I have also try to use `Merchant.new`

```
m = Merchant.new
m.user = u
m.company = "com"
m.save
```

I got the same sql error as stated above, however, when I try `m.user`, it outputs the user obj; with `m`, it outputs the `user` attribute as nil

As stated in the `has_one` method in Rail's API

```
association=(associate) Assigns the associate object, extracts the primary key,
sets it as the foreign key, and saves the associate object.
```

In my case, assigning the user obj doesn't seems to have the primary key extracted and sets it as the foreign key.

Could anyone point me out the problem? What I missed? Thanks!

**Edit**
Here is the Merchant's reflection of User

```
Merchant.reflections[:user]

=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x007f816a8b41e0
@macro=:has_one, @name=:user, @scope=nil, @options={:dependent=>:destroy},
@active_record=Merchant(id: integer, user_id: integer, company: string, 
created_at:datetime, updated_at: datetime), @plural_name="users", @collection=false, 
@class_name="User", @klass=User(id: integer, gender_id: integer, username: string,
first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, passwd: string, salt: binary,
active: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime),
@foreign_key="merchant_id", @active_record_primary_key="id">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `belongs_to` association requires an attribute `<model>_id`. There's no `merchant_id` attribute in the `User` model.

1. Have you run `rake db:migrate`?
2. Is there a migration that adds `merchant_id` to the `users` table, for example `t.integer :merchant_id` or `t.references :merchant` or `add_column :users, :merchant_id, :integer`?

Comment: I don't have migrations as I modify the model on MySQL DB and dump it to schema.rb. I have `merchant_id` on the Merchant model. Since this is a one-to-one association, I just include a `user_id` in the Merchant model. Does rails require to define `merchant_id` in User model as well?

Comment: In that case, your relationship is the wrong way round. It's the side that has the `belongs_to` that's required to have the foreign key. Note: Rails convention is that a model's own primary key is in a column called `id`, while foreign keys are in the form `<model>_id`. You can change it of course... if you like pain.

Answer (score 0):

What a silly mistake! I put has_one and belongs_to in the wrong file. I got it working by  changing `has_one` to `belongs_to` and vice versa.  ;)